# zend search lucene query api: boosting a term

Tags: php, zend-framework, search, lucene, zend-search-lucene

I am using zend search lucene, and would like to add boosts to some of my search terms.
The code is already written using the query construction API as follows.

```
$query->addTerm(new Zend_Search_Lucene_Index_Term($name,'name'), null);
```

I tried writing

```
$query->addTerm(new Zend_Search_Lucene_Index_Term($name . "^10", 'name'), null);
```

But that appears not to work correctly. (I suddenly get no results at all).

This carat syntax  is listed in the [documentation for query language](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.search.lucene.query-language.html#zend.search.lucene.query-language.boosting), but *not* in the docs for [query construction API](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.search.lucene.query-api.html). I know that in some instances the API doesn't behave quite like plain query language. Is this one of those instances?

Is there a function or parameter that adds boost values to terms?

Answer (score 0):

Try outputting your query by doing something like this:

```
$term = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Index_Term($name,'name');
$query = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Search_Query_Term($term);

echo $query;
```

This will allow you to see the query that is being created before you use it to execute a search.